# Office Addin On-Send Feature

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, add-in, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently having problems with the on-send feature on some desktop clients. I have implemented an addin but for some desktop clients emails are blocked from being sent. The email hangs and does not get sent. Is there a way to use on-send by disable for desktop clients. Can i do this in the manifest file or in powershell? Is it even possible to disable on-send for specific platforms. I want to configure my addin to never block emails. I suspect emails are blocked because `event.completed()` close as expected on some Desktop clients.
This is a new thing since the on-send never worked on desktop clients before. Now that it does...i have to deal with this bug somehow

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable an add-in for just desktop clients. It is either enabled for all Win32, Mac and OWA, or off for all. This is true of all add-ins not just OnSend. Though previously this feature was not enabled for Desktop clients, it now is.

Note to unblock e-mails you should be calling event.completed({allowEvent:true}); (or false) to block e-mails. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event?view=word-js-preview

What is your scenario that you need to disable this for Desktop but NOT OWA?

You could also detect what platform you are on an change behavior of your add-in as necessary.

Comment: The thing is that though I do call `event.completed({allowEvent:true});` and it works in some cases. But for some desktop clients, the emails are blocked nonetheless. This is especially difficult to reproduce because it does not happen on all desktop client and only happens sometimes.

Comment: Can you share the client platform(Windows/Mac) and version, where you are seeing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

But the event.completed({allowEvent:true}); also have problem.
For example:

If I install a com app on Outlook then install an on-send add-in.
The problem is, if they both have simultaneous response on-send event. It will stack in an infinite loop.

As an add-in developer, the root cause looks like, event.completed({allowEvent:true}) not only end add-in but also send an 'send' event out. This will trigger a non self sending event response.